# Eclipse syntax color scheme not working correctly

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I switched my Eclipse color scheme using the color scheme plugin.  The example of the syntax highlighting for the theme does not all translate to the editor, the majority of the code displays white.

What it should look like:

[image: http://imgur.com/DyrNk]

What it actually looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h36xq.png]

Is there a setting overriding this somewhere that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: You're sure it's not a bug in that plug-in?  It looks like it's force-ably altering preferences that belong to other plug-ins, after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Aptana Studio plug-in installed, try uninstalling it. Aptana doesn't play well and interferes in Eclipse's color settings.